# Javascript toggle menu with multiple levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm working on a navigation with 3 levels and want use toggle to expand and close those levels. I got it to work with the second level but am struggling with the third level. 
I want the third level(purpose1,purpose2) to open when the second level(Purpose) is clicked.

```
    <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>History</li>
         </ul>
     </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="products">
            <li>Series</li>
            <li>Purpose</li>

        </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>purpose1</li>
            <li>purpose2/li>
         </ul> 
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function(){
 $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
 $(this).find('ul').toggle();

});

$('ul.products').click(function() {
 $('ul.products').not(this).find('ul').hide();
 $(this).find('ul').toggle();

});
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marialena/ejer05py/2/) to illustrate the issue. The actual navigation is much more complex but this should do the job. Any suggestiones are really appreciated!

Comment: which is the 3rd level menu in your example , `purpose1 & 2` ?

Answer (score 0):

clicking in the product li is propagating up to the top level, which is causing the close.

```
$('ul.products').click(function(e) {
   $('ul.products').not(this).find('ul').hide();
   $(this).find('ul').toggle();
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

.

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>History</li>
         </ul>            
     </li>      
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="products">
            <li>Series
                <ul>
                    <li>Series123</li>
                    <li>Series456</li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Purpose
                <ul>
                    <li>purpose1</li>
                    <li>purpose2</li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html is wrong. If the third lvl is to be displayed by clicking "purpose" it shoudl look like this:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="products">
                <li>Series</li>
                <li >Purpose
                    <ul >
                        <li>Series123</li>
                        <li>Series456</li>
                     </ul> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Then just add a class to this thrid lvl list parent and add the jquery fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplified working version, first move you 3rd level `ul` inside the `li`

```
<ul>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>History</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul class="products">

      <li>Series
        <ul>
          <li>Series123</li>
          <li>Series456</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Purpose</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

and here goes the jQuery snippet -

```
$('li.dropdown a').click(function(){
    $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
    $(this).parent('li').find('ul').toggle();

});

$('li.dropdown ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Check the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejer05py/3/)